# Newly added row gets disappear in kendo grid

Tags: kendo-grid, newrow

I have a kendo grid and a AddRow button.On AddRow Button click I am adding a new row to kendo grid.When I click on AddRow button, new row gets added sucessfully but clicking anywhere else in the page except first column of newly added row,row disappears.Here is my code on button click:

```
                          $('#AddRow').click(function () {
                           grid = $('#grdclaimantTypeTips').data("kendoGrid");
                           grid.addRow();
                           row = grid.tbody.find(".k-grid-edit-row");
                           grid.select(row); 
                               }  
 Here is my code for kendo grid:

      @(Html.Kendo().Grid<ClaimPro.Data.ClientAttributeDO>()
                                .Name("grdclaimantTypeTips")
                                .Columns(columns =>
                                {

                                    columns.Bound(Type => Type.claim_type_name).Title(Resource.ClaimType).Width(80).EditorTemplateName("ClientAttributesDDL").EditorViewData(new { columnName = "claim_type_cd" });
                                    columns.Bound(Type => Type.claimant_name).Title(Resource.Claimant).Width(120).ClientTemplate("#=claimant_name_changed#");
                                    columns.Bound(Type => Type.tip).Title(Resource.Tip).Width(200).HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "Wrap" });
                                    columns.Bound(Type => Type.tip).Hidden();
                                    columns.Bound(Type => Type.tip).Hidden();
                                    columns.Bound(Type => Type.id).Hidden();

                                })
                                .Scrollable()
                                .Sortable()
                                .Filterable()

                                .Selectable(selectable =>
                                {
                                    selectable.Mode(GridSelectionMode.Single);
                                    selectable.Type(GridSelectionType.Row);
                                }
                                )
                                .Pageable(pageable => pageable.Input(true).PageSizes((int[])ViewData["DefaultDropdownSize"]))
                                .Resizable(resize => resize.Columns(true))
                                .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell))
                                .Events(e => e.Edit("onEditGrid"))
                                .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                                    .Ajax()
                                    .ServerOperation(false)
                                    .Batch(true)
                                    .Model(model => model.Id(c => c.id))
                                    .Model(model => model.Field(p => p.claimant_name).Editable(false))
                                    .Read(read => read.Action("GetClaimantTypeDetails", "ClientAttribute"))
                                )


                                )
```

Comment: If you are adding a new row to the grid how come you are not using the built in "Create" feature or are you doing additional things to the new row that are not shown. Also do you get any errors being fire into the console at all?

Comment: @DavidShorthose..Yes I am not using Built in "Create" Function.I am adding new row,doing validations and saving the newly added row using seperate javascript functions. If I click on first column of newly added row everything is happening properly.But clicking anywhere else rows gets disappear.I did not get any errors on console.

Comment: Does the row disappear after you have completed editing or does it disappear when you are moving from one cell to the next to edit. Also is there a reason why you have "Type.tip" field listed three times in the columns?

Comment: @DavidShorthose Rows disappearing when I am moving from one cell to next to edit.Three times tip field can be ignored.It should be only once.

Comment: I have added your "Add Row" code to this dojo http://dojo.telerik.com/IviNa and it is working as expected so what is happening the editing/validating code you are doing on the row clientside. What is happening specifically in the "OnEditGrid" event you have added to the grid.

Comment: On "OnEditGrid"  I am not doing much.I am just validating the roles.Only authorised person is having the rights to Edit the Grid.Here is the code on "OnEditGrid"  function onEditGrid(e) {
         e.container.find("input[name=tip]").attr("maxlength", 2000);
        if ((RoleName == 'bto_approvers') || (RoleName == 'bto_authorizer') || (RoleName == 'bto_preloggers') || (RoleName == 'bto_processors') || (RoleName == 'bto_readonly')) {
              var grid = $('#grdclaimantTypeTips').data("kendoGrid");
              grid.closeCell();
        }
     }

Comment: if you take the onEdit event out does this work? I think what may be happening is that this logic is interfering with your ability to edit the cells.

Comment: @DavidShorthose.No after I take out OnEvent it does'nt work.Meanwhile I need that Event.So I cannot remove them.

Comment: The grid itself looks fine so what other javascript do you have running as this could be causing the unexpected behaviour. If you could provide either the code or a sample project with this broken code then that would help.